# enum select in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I've got a problem with selecting enum value in form 
here is a form

```
  =form_for @ticket , remote: true do |f|
    .errors        
    p  
      = f.label :name, class: 'label_hidden' 
      = f.text_field :name, placeholder:'Input your name', class:'form-control'
    p  
      = f.label :email, class: 'label_hidden' 
      = f.email_field :email, placeholder:'Input your email', class:'form-control'
    p  
      = f.label :department, class: 'label_hidden'
      = f.select :department, Ticket.departments.keys , class:'form-control'       
    p
      = f.submit 'Submit', class:'btn btn-default custom'
```

In my db I have a field department that is string type, also in a model I have

```
class Ticket < ActiveRecord::Base
  enum department: [:issue, :qa, :promotion]
  validates :name, :email, :subject, :body, :department, presence: true
end
```

When i send this form - in params everything is ok( the department param is there), also I have permitted this param in controller. Still I recieve "department can't be blank". Where I am wrong?

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow. It'd help us if you could show us the part of the server logs where the params come through (and a few of the lines just after it), so we can see what structure they have. Have you tried creating a ticket manually in the rails console and seeing if it also has the same bug (or if it's just the form)?

Comment: Hello Taryn!! Yeh I've tried - it roled back a transaction all the time!! The thing that helped is I changed string value in db to integer, also I set an ugly type conversion in my params. I believe I don't understand enums in rails ((.

Comment: Should the value for enum in db be distincly integer, when using enums? Also I have a problem that class: 'form controll' does not influence select field at all, could you look at it please?

Comment: Looks like cema-sp has given you the result... the issue is that the values in your enum are symbols, not strings (similar but not the same)... so you need to convert them to a symbol before adding them as a value :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose that you receive enum as a String, so you should convert it with setter method:

```
def department=(val)
    self[:department] = val.to_sym
end
```